# can you make a xml db in saxon like in BaseX

Tags: java, saxon

I want to switch my xquery processor from BaseX to saxon since saxon provides schema query Xquery execution. Is it possible to create a xml database in saxon like in BaseX ? 
Tried reading the javaDoc but cant find any analogy for basex DB in saxon.
https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/

Answer (score 0):

No, Saxon has no database capabilities.

For general information about Saxon you want the high-level documentation at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!about rather than the Javadoc API specs.

On the page "Using XQuery" it says:

> Saxon is an in-memory processor. Unless you can take advantage of
>   streaming, Saxon is designed to process source documents that fit in
>   memory.